# That is IOS's code ,how to make it in Android

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, webview

```
(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *lJs = @"document.documentElement.innerHTML";

    NSString *lHtml = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:lJs];

    NSLog(@"html内容:%@",lHtml1);  

    // youku,tudou,ku6 ,souhu
    NSString *lJs2 = @"(document.getElementsByTagName(\"video\")[0]).src";  

    NSString *lm3u8 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:lJs2];

    NSLog(@"video source:%@",lm3u8);
}
```

How to use that code in android webview?

Comment: Wanna show us what you have so far in Android so we can help you fix it?

Comment: plz tag it as Android so dat it will shows an android question..and what ur code does..describe here?